# Django ORM: dynamically add multiple conditions for ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, orm

Let's say that we have Django models defined as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)

class Article(models.Model):
  title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  text=models.TextField() 
  tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

And we have a list of tags:

```
tag_list = ['tag1','tag2','tag3']
```

The goal is to select articles that have all tags from `tag_list`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883391/django-manytomany-filter-with-more-than-one-condition) shows a way to achive this with filter conditions added sequentially:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(Q(tag__name=tag_list[0])).filter(Q(tag__name=tag_list[1])).filter(Q(tag__name=tag_list[2]))
```

But we need to add conditions dynamically. The query below doesn't work:

```
qlist=[]
for tag in tag_list:
  qlist.append(Q(tag__name=tag))
articles = Articles.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, qlist))
```

I ended up querying articles that have at least one tag from the list and then manually filtering query results:

```
qlist=[]
qlist.append(Q(tag__name__in=tag_list))
articles = Articles.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, qlist)).distinct()

for article in articles:
  article_tag_list=[]
  for tag in article.tag.all():
    article_tag_list.append(tag.name)
  if set(tag_list).issubset(set(article_tag_list)):
    ...
```

Is there a way to add query conditions for `ManyToManyField` dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
q_objects = Q()
for tag in tag_list:
  q_objects &= Q(tag__name=tag)
articles = Articles.objects.filter(q_objects)
```

I've used the pattern above many times, and it always worked for me.

**UPDATE:** While generally speaking this method works, it doesn't apply to this problem. The code above requires all condition to be true for a single related object. In this case this means there would have to be a single tag with three different names, which is clearly nonsensical.

This is the code that ended up working for OP:

```
for tag in tag_list:
    articles = articles.filter(tag__name=tag)
```

[Django docs provide a detailed explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) of the difference between putting multiple rules in one `filter()` and having them in multiple `filter()`s (when it comes to querying multi-valued relationships).

Comment: Ludwik, for some reason this method does not work for me. Multiple conditions like 'Q(tag_name=tag)&(text__icontains=word)' are indeed combined with such a method, but once I add multiple conditions for the 'ManyToManyField' empty set is returned.

Comment: I'd try debugging other elements. Do you really have a single articles with all the tags you've got in the `tag_list` list ? Does the list really contains what you think it contains? If you search for those tags manually (doing `.filter(Q(tag__name='tag1') & Q(tag__name='tag2') & Q(tag__name='tag3'))`) is the result really different?

Comment: Ludwik, I did debug it like you say. Such manual filter gives an empty set as well. I've found another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474310/django-filter-a-model-with-multiple-parameters-for-a-single-manytomanyfield) saying that the way to go is to chain filters `for tag in tag_list: articles=articles.filter(tag__name=tag)`

Comment: Yeah, that should also work. Does it work in your case?

Comment: Ludwik, yes, it does work. And I've seen evidences, like in comments to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883391/django-manytomany-filter-with-more-than-one-condition) that the method you originally proposed does not work.

Comment: Ok, you are right, generally speaking they both work, but there is a difference. My method would require all condition to be true *for a single related object*. In your case this would require a single tag to have three different names, which is clearly nonsensical. My mistake.

Comment: If you 404 on the link in the reply, [use this updated link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) instead